# HTML-to-WordPress: Dropdown Navigation Menu

Tags: navigation, html, dropdown

so I've been searching around in the hope somebody also had this issue.. But I can't find any. I've currently created a Wordpress template out of a hardcoded HTML template for somebody.

Now here's the problem... He already had coded the dropdown function in CSS so it was my job to port it over to Wordpress but it doesn't seem to work out very well.

This is how it should look like (Note that there are three rows because there are three categories within the menu itself):
[image: This is how it should like]

This is the HTML from the hardcoded template;

```
<li class="green">
    <a href="#">Evenementen</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu_title" href="#">Evenementen</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Braderie</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Jaarmarkten</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu_title" href="#">Bedrijfsfeesten</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sportfeesten</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Cateringbus</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Filmlocatiebus</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu_title" href="#">Kinderfeesten</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Schoolfeesten</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Familiedagen</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I myself have so far is in the header.php at the moment:

```
     <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></li>
     <?php wp_nav_menu('title_li=&depth=2'); ?>
```

Functions.php :

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_parent_class' );
function add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {

$parents = array();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
        $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
    }
}

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
        $item->classes[] = 'submenu'; 
    }
}

return $items;}
```

EDIT: I've tried everything to look at the codex of wp_nav_menu, but I can't seem to make anything out of it. Someone told me that I'm not using it correctly, the thing is: Where am I not using it correctly? Is it in functions.php or header.php? I just need to port it over as it seems the most safest thing to do. I've never done such a dropdown menu before which is why I'm asking for a push in the right way.

Comment: You're not using `wp_nav_menu()` correctly. Please [refer to the Codex entry for `wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), correct your usage, and then report back with any issues remaining.

Comment: I thank you for your quick reply, but could you explain what you mean about me not using the wp_nav_menu correctly? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Please read the linked Codex entry. It explains correct usage of `wp_nav_menu()`. For further reference, read [the Codex entry on Custom Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus). Explaining the entire implementation of the feature is too broad-scoped for WPSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way is put:

```
 wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Top menu','menu_class' => 'top_menu'));
```

And then force your html classes to wordpress, or simply 5 min rewrite css rules, classies names for wordpress.

Wordpress uses ul li ul li ul li, and so on structure, and there is no problem to fix it.

Comment: You need to use `theme_location`, **not** `menu`, in your `wp_nav_menu()` call.

Comment: There is no metter :)

Comment: Actually, yes there is: a very significant matter. Using `menu` will force the `wp_nav_menu()` call to look for a user-defined nav menu with a specific name. Using `theme_location` will use whatever user-defined nav menu the user has applied to the registered Theme Location. Using `menu` in place of `theme_location` essentially bypasses the entire purpose of using `wp_nav_menu()` in the first place.

Comment: How can you force the HTML classes to Wordpress if I may ask?

Comment: Rewrite html for wordpress class names. For exampe `.menu ul li.current_page_item`

Comment: Rewrite html and css for wordpress class names. For exampe `.menu ul li.current_page_item` if in your html is `<ul class="submenu-etc"` chech for wordpress syntax there will be class childer. Rewrite css from submenu to childer. For example: old css `.menu ul.submenu` need to rewrite on `.menu ul.children` and so on also on other posible menu css rules. And you dont need a rewrite function in your functions.php code.

Comment: I have fixed my issue and went for the rewriting classes solution. Allthough it didn't look perfectly, so I've asked the person who made the menu to rewrite the part that I've missed. So everything came out great.